# Incompatible types: DetailOneFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have problem in my code

error is

> incompatible types: DetailOneFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
>   in Android
>
> incompatible types: DetailTwoFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
>   in Android

Which is wrong?

**this is DetailActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intnet;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.adnroidtown.albaplanet.R;
import org.adnroidtown.albaplanet.review_view.Review1Activity;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager pager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        //메인 액티비티에서 넘겨받은 인텐트 -시작-
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_img);
        TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_store);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        iv.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("img", 0));
        tvName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"));

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.detail_viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(manager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
        // mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager1);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, Review1Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**this is PagerAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment frag = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            frag = new DetailOneFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            frag = new DetailTwoFragment();
            break;
        }
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = " ";
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            title = "Game";
            break;
        case 1:
            title = "Movie";
            break;
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

**this is DetailOneFragment.java**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import org.adnroidtown.albaplanet.R;

public class DetailOneFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailOneFragment(){
    // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

**This is error ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: in your DetailOnFragment, change import android.app.Fragment; with import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: that: `import android.app.Fragment;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

in your fragments

Comment: your welcome :) don't forget to upvote and mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

See your screenshot. You Import/extend `android.app.Fragment;`in DetailOneFragment and use `android.app.support...Fragment` in your other class

Answer (score 0):

As of 02-2021 the solution above did work for me but i had to replace :

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

instead